# How to add resources in jQuery full calendar dynamically through a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `updateCalendar()` function which adds the events dynamically but I'm unable to do it for resources. I have a JSON resource Array which I need to load in the `resources[]` but there is no way I can do it. I have tried it by getting the resource array through URL but it also not working.

Here is my piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        defaultView: 'resourceDay',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        resources: {
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/protected/appointment/getResourceList",
            type: "GET"
        },
        events: [],
        // the 'ev' parameter is the mouse event rather than the resource 'event'
        // the ev.data is the resource column clicked upon
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, ev) {
            console.log(start);
            console.log(end);
            console.log(ev.data); // resources
        },
        eventClick: function(event) {
            var value = '${scheduleByLocationPage}';
            document.getElementById("scheduleByLocation").action = 'FetchAppointmentDetails?id=' + event.id
                + '&problemAppointment1=' + event.problemCode + '&referredFrom=' + value;
            document.getElementById("scheduleByLocation").submit();
            console.log(event);
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    });

    updateCalender();

    $('#locationID').change(function() {
        updateCalender();
    });

    $('#searchDate').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            updateCalender();
        }
    });


    function updateCalender() {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("locationID");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        var serviceName = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
        var date = document.getElementById("searchDate").value;
        var eventArray = [ [] ];
        var title = '';
        var start = '';
        var end = '';
        var allDay = '';
        var date1 = '';
        var id = '';
        var problemCode = '';
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
        var goCalndarDate = '';

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $('#scheduleFor').html('Schedule for ' + serviceName + ' on ' + date);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/protected/appointment/ScheduleByLocation",
            data: {
                locationID: selectedValue,
                filterDate: date,
                browserTimeZone: n
            },
            success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                eventArray = JSON.parse(xhr.getResponseHeader('eventArray'));
                goCalndarDate = eventArray[0].searchDate;

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', goCalndarDate);

                for (var x = 1; x < eventArray.length; x++) {
                    title = eventArray[x].title;
                    start = new Date(eventArray[x].start);
                    end = new Date(eventArray[x].end);
                    allDay = eventArray[x].allDay;
                    date1 = eventArray[x].date;
                    id = eventArray[x].id;
                    problemCode = eventArray[x].problemCode;
                    offset = eventArray[x].offset;

                    var newEvent = {
                        id: id,
                        problemCode: problemCode,
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay,
                        resources: ['resource2'],
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        backgroundColor: '#000000'
                    };

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date1);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, 'stick');
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("Ajax error " + eval(error));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before initiating the full calendar, make an ajax call to your resource URL and then initiate the full calendar on the success function of the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your resource url here',
    type 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'resourceDay',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            resources: {
                id: data.id, // Or whatever object properties you need from data
                title: data.tile
            },
            events: [],
            // the 'ev' parameter is the mouse event rather than the resource 'event'
            // the ev.data is the resource column clicked upon
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, ev) {
                console.log(start);
                console.log(end);
                console.log(ev.data); // resources
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                var value = '${scheduleByLocationPage}';
                document.getElementById("scheduleByLocation").action = 'FetchAppointmentDetails?id=' + event.id
                + '&problemAppointment1=' + event.problemCode +  '&referredFrom=' + value;
                document.getElementById("scheduleByLocation").submit();
                console.log(event);
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                console.log(event);
            }
        });
    }
});
```